# is it possible to override core plugin method by custom preference method?

Tags: magento2, plugin, preference

is possible to override core plugin method by preference?

Means I need to override **afterXyz** method in my module by using preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the Plugin with `disabled="true"`. For example:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action">
    <plugin name="storeCheck" disabled="true" />
    <plugin name="storeCheckCustom" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\StoreCheck" sortOrder="99" />
</type>
```